# UITableview Does Not Scroll Up

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiscrollview

I am having some scrolling issues with my tableview.

- Swiping/panning upwards, the tableview scrolls down.
- **Swiping/panning down does not work, the tableview stays rigid.**
- Swiping/panning upwards, and then quickly swiping downwards works
  (scrolls up).

**Does anyone have any idea why something like this may happen?**

Each cell has an image, and a couple of buttons.

I am using SDWebImage, and this issues occurs even once the images are downloaded and cached.

The imageviews' userInteractionEnabled are set to YES, so that should not be a problem either.

Comment: Please comment below, if you'd like any extra info, etc.

Comment: Better you can use TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView instead of UITableView.

Comment: @AnandGautam , I am confused, how is TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView relevant? The keyboard is not the issue here.

Comment: @GangstaGraham, yes your question is too short. Read Cells and Table View Performance topic from this document http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7

Comment: @iAmbitious I read through it, everything seems fine.

Comment: Please show some of your code. Is there a `UIGestureRecognizer` around your tableView?

Comment: If you remove the SDWebImage does this still happen?

Comment: Do you have any other UIGestureRegcognizers anywhere in that view hierarchy? In the cells, perhaps? (@liuyaodong asked too!)

Comment: Nope, I don't have any other UIGestureRecognizers in the app.@RandyJames

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that scrolling, in general, did not work at the top 70% of my screen.

So only when swiping down past the 70% threshold, would the app detect scrolling, hence it would scroll down.

This was because I was using a Dropdown Menu that I found on GitHub (it covered the top 70% of the screen when it was open), that unfortunately interfered with the scrolling, even when hidden.

So basically, for anyone who has the same problem in the future, **check for interfering views**, that may be affecting the scrolling performance. **Especially look for views and other elements from *external* code/libraries**.

If this is not the case, **check UIGestureRecognizers** as suggested by @RandyJames and @liuyadong in the comments above.